# 'NoneType' object is not callable django

Tags: python-decorators

```
@admin.site.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'author', 'publish', 'status')
    list_filter = ('status', 'created', 'publish', 'author')
```

Please help me out because i dont know what is the problem

Comment: Your question looks as if you did not spend very much time writing it. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.